# The alias for "Europe/Moscow" timezone is "W-SU". What does it stands for?

Tags: timezone, standards

Wild guess:
a) "SU" stands for Soviet Union;
b) "W" stands for Western

Thorough internet search didn't help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Can you suggest a proper place to ask this question?

Comment: Seems like you're right: https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2006-May/013582.html

Answer (score 0):

As of today, a google search found these links and others:

```
"Country code(s)    TZ database name    Area(s) covered    Type    UTC offset        Time zone       Source file    Notes
...
                                                                   STD     DST       abbreviation
RU                 W-SU                <blank>            Link     +03:00  +03:00    MSK             backward        Link to Europe/Moscow
..."
--https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones


"...    
The current W-SU time zone offset is:
UTC/GMT +3 hours    
...
This time zone does not change for daylight savings.    
...    
Time zones in MSD, MSK
Europe/Moscow"
--https://www.travelmath.com/time-zone/W-SU
```

It is also in the TZ DB:

```
Mac_3.2.57$find . -type f -exec grep -Hn 'W-SU'  {} \;
./backward:127:Link Europe/Moscow       W-SU
./frickenAll:15370:Link Europe/Moscow       W-SU
Mac_3.2.57$cat backward | head -n 137 | tail -n 20
Link    America/New_York    US/Eastern
Link    Pacific/Honolulu    US/Hawaii
Link    America/Indiana/Knox    US/Indiana-Starke
Link    America/Detroit     US/Michigan
Link    America/Denver      US/Mountain
Link    America/Los_Angeles US/Pacific
Link    Pacific/Pago_Pago   US/Samoa
Link    Etc/UTC         UTC
Link    Etc/UTC         Universal
Link    Europe/Moscow       W-SU
Link    Etc/UTC         Zulu


# Two-part names that were renamed mostly to three-part names in 1995

# Link  TARGET              LINK-NAME   #= TARGET1
Link    America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires  America/Buenos_Aires
Link    America/Argentina/Catamarca America/Catamarca
Link    America/Argentina/Cordoba   America/Cordoba
Link    America/Indiana/Indianapolis    America/Indianapolis
Mac_3.2.57$
```